# Is it legal to make money off a youtube downloader or similar unofficial YouTube service?

Tags: united-states, online, is-x-legal

There are many online services that let one download the audio and video from YouTube videos. Is it legal for the owners of such services to make money off these services, for example, to charge per download or to have revenue generating ads on their websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is certainly no law prohibiting it so the only restrictions are those that are in the [contract](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service) between YouTube and the third party. On a brief reading I cannot see anything that prohibits monetisation.